# Primitives used to convert LSTM NDL to Python in CNTK

Tags: python, lstm, cntk

I’m trying to convert an LSTM NDL config to Python, but not able to find the support for following NDL primitives

- Delay  - How to pass argument in delay of a variable defined later in the network? Eg for peep hole LSTM, cell state variable eg c_t is defined later, but delay is needed to get c_t_minus_1 cell state eg c_t_minus_1 = Delay(c_t). However, Python doesn’t allow variables(eg c_t) to be used first and defined later.
- RowStack, RowSlice – Are there any substitutes for these primitives? If not how to implement them in python? Can we operate on variables as if they are numpy arrays?
- DiagTime vs ElementTimes – Is there any difference between them for vector element wise multiplication? Also is DiagTimes in supported in python?
- Parameter initialization – How to Initialize parameters from file in python and set computeGradient as false. I can’t find any support or examples for this.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answers from CNTK team - https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Port-LSTM-NDL-primitives-to-Python

1. you need to use a placeholder_variable and later a call to replace_placeholders. Here’s a simple example use: https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Implement-an-attention-mechanism
2. use splice
3. use element wise multiplication (a.k.a *)
4. use constants. You can specify the initial value via a numpy array. There are many ways to load a text (or other) file into a numpy array. np.loadtxt should work but I haven’t tried it.